# conflicting NULL/NOT NULL declarations for column "id_bank_card" of table "bill"

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I Got a table BILL which is associated to another table BANK_CARD as follows:

```
create table BILL (
    id_bill              BIGSERIAL          not null,
    id_bank_card         BIGSERIAL          null,
    id_registred_user    BIGSERIAL          not null,
    reference_number     INT4                 null,
    purchase_date        DATE                 null,
    bill_status          VARCHAR(50)          null,
    payment_method       VARCHAR(50)          null,
    constraint PK_BILL primary key (id_bill)
);

create table BANK_CARD (
    id_bank_card         BIGSERIAL          not null,
    id_registred_user    BIGSERIAL          not null,
    card_type            VARCHAR(50)          null,
    card_number          INT4                 null,
    expiring_date        DATE                 null,
    cipher               INT4                 null,
    constraint PK_BANK_CARD primary key (id_bank_card)
);
```

The table BILL has a 0..1 association with the table BANK_CARD, and BANK_CARD has a 1..n association with table BILL.

But when i execute my sql script i get the following error:

```
conflicting NULL/NOT NULL declarations for column "id_bank_card" of table "bill"
```

Because the relationship BILL and BANK_CARD is 0..1 the foreign key id_bank_card can be null in the table bill, so i don't understand why i get this error.

Any help please?
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have TWO serials in one table? Why do you have THREE serials in one table?

Comment: With BIGSerial, it can't allow null,  with serial its possible.

Answer (score 7):

You are confusing data type definitions for primary and foreign keys. A `bigserial` is a generator of values of the `bigint` type. The foreign keys should use that data type. See table definitions below. Also, use of the `NULL` clause is redundant as that is the default behaviour. Primary keys can not be `NULL` so `NOT NULL` there is also redundant.

```
create table bank_card (
    id_bank_card         bigserial,
    id_registred_user    bigint references <user table>,
    card_type            VARCHAR(50),
    card_number          INT4,
    expiring_date        DATE,
    cipher               INT4,
    constraint PK_BANK_CARD primary key (id_bank_card)
);

create table bill (
    id_bill              BIGSERIAL,
    id_bank_card         bigint references bank_card,
    id_registred_user    bigint references <user table>,
    reference_number     INT4,
    purchase_date        DATE,
    bill_status          VARCHAR(50),
    payment_method       VARCHAR(50),
    constraint pk_bill primary key (id_bill)
);
```

Comment: I had accidentally used serial instead of int.

Comment: BigSerial vs BigInt ? what's difference ?

Comment: @TejasTank Read up on the PostgreSQL documentation here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL

Answer (score -1):

If you are using **Java**+PostgreSQL:

this can happen if you accidentially insert **null strings** into your statement.

```
String N = System.getProperty("line.seperator");
```

Returned null, screwing up my sql statement.

**FIXES: (Choose One)**

```
String N = System.lineSeparator();
String N = "\n";
```

Exact string as it appeared in my code:

---

```
    String CT =(""
 //:+"---------10--------20--------30-------39
 //:+"0123456789012345678901234567890123456789
    +"CREATE TABLE t_1(             "+N//:0
    +"id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY         "+N//:30
    +"    ,c_1    INT               "+N//:60
    +"    ,c_2    VARCHAR  (255)    "+N//:90
    +"    ,c_3    CHARACTER( 8 )    "+N//:120
    +"    ,c_4    BOOLEAN           "+N//:150
    +"    ,c_5    BYTEA             "+N//:180
    +"    ,c_6    DATE              "+N//:210
    +");                            "  //:240
    );;
```

Exact Error Message when N==null instead of "\n":

---

> ```
> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: 
> ERROR: conflicting NULL/NOT NULL declarations 
>        for column "nullid" of table "t_1"
> ```

Stack: **Java+Heroku+Tomcat9+PostGreSQL 9.5.13**